# Эффективный дебаг рекурсии

Tags: java, рекурсия, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Хочу создать сбалансированное, отсортированное дерево, для того чтобы отрабатывать методы вставки, поиска, подсчета размера и глубины дерева.

Вопрос:

- что не так с моей реализацией, выпадает на NullPionter;
- какой способ дебага рекурсии вы используете? Или с практикой само приходит ?

```
public class DDS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(1, null, null);
        BinaryTreeUtils.initTreeNode(node, 3, 0);
    }
}

class BinaryTreeUtils {
    public static TreeNode initTreeNode(TreeNode root, int heigth, int start) {
        return heigth == 0 ? 
            null : 
            new TreeNode(
                start, 
                initTreeNode(root.left, heigth - 1, start - 1),
                initTreeNode(root.right, heigth - 1, start + 2)
            );
    }
}

class TreeNode {

    public int value;
    public TreeNode left;
    public TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(int value, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте реализацию TreeNode.

Comment: Добавил ++++++++

Comment: Чем дебаг рекурсии отличается от просто дебага кода?

Comment: Тем что глубина рекурсии, и конкретные данные на каждой итерации тяжело уловимы

Comment: NPE у вас выпадает потому, что первый Node вы инициализируете с `.., null, null`, затем передаете эти null в последующий вызов initTreeNode, который уже не может вызвать left или right у нулла